# How to train end-to-end CNN?

Tags: caffe

While using caffe as

> ./build/tools/caffe train --solver=models/Handmade/solver.prototxt

caffe also gets into "phase: TEST" but I have no test data. I only want to train the parameters on my training data, so I haven't used "phase: Test" in "train.prototxt", which causes error. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you can completely omit the test phase but it's possible to train your model without needing a separate test set. It's also possible to prevent the solver from ever switching to the test phase.

Reuse your training data for the test phase. You can do so by duplicating your data layer and specifying it for the test phase.

To limit computations to the training phase only increase the value of `test_interval` in your solver definition to a number larger than your training set or, better, larger than `max_iter`. This prevents the solver from ever switching to the test phase.

I find it a bit odd to train a model without wanting to know how to does on a separate set of data points.

Comment: You mean there is no way to avoid testing?

Comment: Found that if we don't use phase:TRAIN/TEST in train.prototxt then it uses same file in train as well as test, but as the file is already being locked by train, it can't use it for testing causing deadlock. So, better to use a different file (only file name differs) with same content for test.

Comment: You don't run into this problem if you duplicate the layer with two different phases and reuse the same sources. At least for lmdb.

Comment: ypx, even on duplicating the layer with different phases but same source, it doesn't proceed. It seems to be on deadlock. Only on different sources, it proceeds.

Comment: @vivkul odd, I haven't had this problem before. But you could create a dummy test datset + setting `test_interval` to > `max_iter` to skip testing.